# Query regarding dbf file fields

Tags: dbf

there is a dbf file and a text document explaining the list of files in it. Is it the case that the fields in the doc are always present in the dbf for every row?
I am beginning to work with dbf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Each row (or record) is a fixed size in the dbf file, and each field takes up a fixed amount of space in that row.

Even Memo fields, which can hold an arbitrary amount of data, only occupy a fixed amount in the dbf file itself -- an integer reference to where in the separate memo file that field's data starts.